# FullCalendar JQuery plugin set calEvent.allDay = false, in agendaView moving events make them disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar JQuery plugin, when I set calEvent.allDay = false; in eventReceive function and switch to agendaDay view, if I try to move events around they disappear.  If I remove the setting to all Day completely, then when I go to agendaDay View the events are placed in the allDay event section. I can move them wherever I want then, without a problem, but I wanted to set the times internally before I switched to agendaDay view.  Anyone know a way around this?  Not sure how to do code here (I am a newbie), so will include it here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var screenLimit = 12;   
    var scenes = ["FADE IN",
    "LATER THAT DAY",
    "THE NEXT DAY",
    "TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER",
    "THE NEXT DAY",
    "LATER THAT DAY",
    "TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER",
    "ONE OR TWO DAYS LATER",
    "THE NEXT DAY",
    "LATER THAT DAY",
    "ONE OR TWO DAYS LATER",
    "TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER"];

    var fakeresponse = '["FADE IN","LATER THAT DAY","THE NEXT DAY","TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER","THE NEXT DAY","LATER THAT DAY","TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER","ONE OR TWO DAYS LATER","THE NEXT DAY","LATER THAT DAY","ONE OR TWO DAYS LATER","TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER"]';

    var obj = JSON.parse(fakeresponse);

    if (obj == null) {
        var listlength = scenes.length;
        if (listlength < screenLimit) {
            for(i=0;i<listlength;i++) { 
                var lstid = "Sc" + (i+1);
                document.getElementById(lstid).innerHTML = scenes[i];
            }
            for(i=listlength;i<screenLimit;i++) {   
                var lstid1 = "Sc" + (i+1);
                document.getElementById(lstid1).style.display = "none";
            }   
        } else {
            for(i=0;i<scenes.length;i++) {  
                if (screenLimit > i) {
                    var lstid = "Sc"+(i+1);
                    document.getElementById(lstid).innerHTML = scenes[i];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        var listlength = obj.length;
        if (listlength < screenLimit) {
            for(i=0;i<listlength;i++) { 
                var lstid = "Sc" + (i+1);
                document.getElementById(lstid).innerHTML = obj[i];
            }
            for(i=listlength;i<screenLimit;i++) {   
                var lstid1 = "Sc" + (i+1);
                document.getElementById(lstid1).style.display = "none";
            }   
        } else {
            for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++) { 
                if (screenLimit > i) {
                    var lstid = "Sc"+(i+1);
                    document.getElementById(lstid).innerHTML = obj[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }


        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            });

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        var currDate;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prevYear,prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next,nextYear agendaDay month'
            },
            buttonText: {
                agendaDay: 'Action Scheduler',
                month: 'Scene Scheduler'
            },
            editable: true,
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            slotDuration: '00:05:00',
            defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
            scrollTime: '09:00:00',
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            drop: function() {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            eventReceive: function(calEvent) {
                currDate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date
//              calEvent.allDay = false;
//              calEvent.overlap = false;

                var sdate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date
                sdate.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
                sdate.time('09:00:00');   // Set a default start time.
                calEvent.start = sdate;

                var edate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date
                edate.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
                edate.time('09:30:00');   // Set a default start time.
                calEvent.end = edate;

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                    if (calEvent.start.format() == event.start.format() && calEvent.title != event.title) {
                        calEvent.start = edate;
                        var nedate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of dropped date
                        nedate.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
                        nedate.time('10:00:00');   // Set a default start time.
                        calEvent.end = nedate;
                    }           
                });
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
            },
            viewRender: function(view,element) {
                if (view.name == "agendaDay") {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currDate);
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

    #wrap {
        width: 950px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #external-events {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: left;
    }

    #external-events h4 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

    #external-events h5 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    #external-events .fc-event {
        margin: 10px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #external-events p {
        margin: 1.5em 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #666;
    }

    #external-events p input {
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #calendar {
        float: right;
        width: 700px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrap'>

        <div id='external-events'>
            <h4>Story Navigator</h4>
            <h5>Byte Me!</h5>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc1'>Sc 1 - FADE IN</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc2'>Sc 2 - LATER THAT DAY</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc3'>Sc 3 - THE NEXT DAY</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc4'>Sc 4 - TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc5'>Sc 5 - THE NEXT DAY</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc6'>Sc 6 - LATER THAT DAY</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc7'>Sc 7 - TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc8'>Sc 8 - ONE OR TWO DAYS LATER</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc9'>Sc 9 - THE NEXT DAY</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc10'>Sc 10 - LATER THAT DAY</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc11'>Sc 11 - ONE OR TWO DAYS LATER</div>
            <div class='fc-event' id='Sc12'>Sc 12 - TWO OR THREE DAYS LATER</div>
        </div>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
        <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No FullCalendar experts out there?  Help!  am on a deadline for this.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, can anyone tell me how to create a second sidebar on the right side of the calendar (to go with the already existing one on the left)? Nothing I try seems to work, and have consulted Google and multiple books.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FullCalendar is not happy with me setting an end time for the events I drag and drop as I drop them.  It works fine if I just set a start time and let defaultTimedEventDuration set the end for me.  So code should be:

```
        eventReceive: function(calEvent) {
            calEvent.allDay = false;

            currDate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date

            var sdate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date
            sdate.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
            sdate.time('09:00:00');   // Set a default start time.
            calEvent.start = sdate;

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                if (calEvent.start.format() == event.start.format() && calEvent.title != event.title) {
                    var edate = $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start.format());  // Create a clone of the dropped date
                    edate.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
                    edate.time('09:05:00');   // Set a default start time.

                    calEvent.start = edate;
                }           
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
        },
```

Thanks.